# Use struct names in LuaJIT FFI error messages

Tags: luajit

When I do something wrong in LuaJIT FFI, I can get an error message like "Cannot convert struct 129 to struct 141". How can I understand which structs are meant? In my code, all C structs have a `typedef`, which FFI of course knows about, since it can be used in `ffi.new`; how do I get LuaJIT to use this typedef as the name?

Comment: Are you defining the structure multiple times? `typedef struct { ... } name` should work as long as you only define it once (otherwise you try to define it to a different structure).

Answer (score 0):

Answer found while looking at other LuaJIT questions: I need to declare structs as `typedef struct $name { ... } $name`, not `typedef struct { ... } $name` which I had.